# When does the orthogonal fitted value become itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, linear-regression, projection-matrices

Let $m \times a$ full-column matrix $B$, and define the projection matrix onto its column space as $P(B)=B(B'B)^{-1}B'$ which is $m\times m$ matrix.

Consider a rectangular matrix $A$, where $A$ is $m \times n$ and the rank of $A$ is $n$. More specifically, $A$ has a specific form such that $A=[A_1'|0']'$, where $A_1$ is $n\times n$ full-rank matrix and $0'$ denotes $n \times (m-n)$ zero matrix. Note that $a \leq n \leq m$ holds.

Define the fitted value as $P(B)A=B(B'B)^{-1}B'A$. In which case the fitted value becomes itself? In other words, I'm wondering about the conditions on $A$ or $B$ that make $P(B)A=B(B'B)^{-1}B'A=A$ hold.

Comment: The columns of $A$ must be in the column space of $B$, that is, $A=B\tilde{A}$ for some $\tilde{A}$. Then $P(B)A=P(B)B\tilde{A}=B\tilde{A}=A$.

Comment: Does it also mean that the column space of $B$ should span each columns of $A$?

Comment: Also if $a \leq n$, then can $A$ be a full-rank matrix? Because if $A=B\widetilde{A}$ holds, then $rank(A)\leq min(rank(B),rank(\widetilde{A}))$, so $rank(A)\leq a$ is satisfied. So $A$ can't be a full-column matrix?

Comment: Is there any way to make $A$ be a full-column matrix and $P(B)A=A$? Is it mathematically impossible? Please help me.

Comment: $P(B)A=A$ if only if $\mathrm{Im}(A)\subset\mathrm{Im}(B)$. It is not hence possible that $A$ has more columns than $B$ and still have full column rank.

Comment: Thanks. Then such an $A$ in my question does not exist. One last question: what does $Im(A)$ mean?

Comment: Image (column space) of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projection of any vector $\mathbf{x}$ that "lives" in the column space the design matrix $X$ will be $\mathbb{x}$ itself. Let us drop the intercept term for the sake of simplicity. As such, the $H$ matrix projects any vector into the space that is spanned by your independent variables $\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_p$. Now, any vector that can be presented as a linear combination of $\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_p$ belongs - by definition - to the space spanned by these vectors. The so called "fitted values" are nothing more but a linear combination of $\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_p$ with the (unique vector of) coefficients $\hat{\beta}_1,..., \hat{\beta}_p$, hence the fitted values "live" in the column space of $X$. Hence, when you project the fitted vector you get the vector itself as the "distance" between the spanned space and the fitted values is zero.